# link java bytecode (class files) with java-command

Tags: command-line, java

Is it possible to directly bind all *.class files with the java command?

At the moment I run java-files like:

```
java myprog args
```

Is it possible to simple type

```
myporg args
```

ok, this is not a very important question, but it would be nice to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java -cp "/path/to/package/directory/or/directory/with/classes:/another/path" <class_name> [args]
```

you can use alias

```
alias <prog_name>='java -cp '"/path"' <class_name>'
```

and then

```
<prog_name> [args]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can always set the CLASSPATH variable to the location where all your class files are located or packages are located.

*export CLASSPATH=/path/to/package/directory/or/directory/with/classes:/another/path*

you can very well add this line in $HOME/.bashrc file.

After that you can just say java myprog args

hope this solves.